# Show that "ans += resultList[i] - 2 * resultList[i-1]" in the function is the right expression to use when trying to convert ROMAN NUMBERS to INTEGERS

Tags: proof-explanation, number-systems, python

I was looking for creative ways in which someone could convert a valid **roman number** to an **integer** via algorithms in the web, and from all of the examples I found, there was one in particular that caught my attention because of the way it made it, it was a program built on `Python` which used a single function called `roman_to_int` that took the `input` of the user as the variable `roman_string` to use as argument in the function, see below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def roman_to_int(roman_string):
    if not isinstance(roman_string, str) or roman_string is None:
        return 0

    numberDict = {
        "I": 1, "V": 5, "X": 10,
        "L": 50, "C": 100, "D": 500, "M": 1000
    }
    resultList = []
    for val in roman_string:
        for key, value in numberDict.items():
            if val == key:
                resultList.append(value)
    print(resultList)
    nElem = len(resultList)
    if nElem <= 0:
        return None
    ans = 0
    for i in range(nElem):
        if i > 0 and resultList[i] > resultList[i-1]:
            ans += resultList[i] - 2 * resultList[i-1]
        else:
            ans += resultList[i]
    return ans
```

So, if wanted to print the conversion of the roman number like `MMMC` to integer using this function, I use following the sentence:

```
print(roman_to_int('MMMC'))
```

Which would print:

> 3100

Which is correct. Another correct output also happens with `MMMMMDCCC`:

> 5800

Etc...

Now, keep in mind that I understand *how* the function above works, but I don't get *why* does the function substract 2 times the value at the previous position in the array `resultList` from the value at current position in the array `resultList`

(i.e. `ans += resultList[i] - 2 * resultList[i-1]`)

Unfortunately, I'm too uneducated to type my question in a valid Math Notation, can someone assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code `ans += resultList[i] - 2 * resultList[i-1]` only executes when `resultList[i] > resultList[i-1]` , which doesn't happen often in roman numbers.

In fact, this is done do cover the case like `IX` being meant to represent the number $9$. If you get `IX`, you will

1. Add $1$, because you first process the character `I`
2. Then you notice that the next character is `X` representing $10$.
3. Because $10>1$, you now know that you added $1$ too many, so you need to subtract $1$, and you also need to add $10-1$. So alltogether you need to add $10 - 1$, and also subtract $-1$, so you need to add $10-2\cdot 1$.

The same applies if you meed something like $CM$. Again, you first add $100$, then add $1000-2\cdot 100$.

Comment: My brain went brrrrrrrrrr so it has to undo its addition in the previous step. I get that for ```IV``` it would first add 1 for the ```I```, then notice that the next value (5) is larger, thus having to subtract 5-1 and also remove the previously added 1 to come up at the final solution. 

But why is this guaranteed to work with really big numbers? such as 100k in roman? I mean, this is just a very weird of converting a roman number to an integer number.

Comment: @Noah199520 It works on every case where a smaller number is put in front of a larger number.